# Text distorted when using scale in fabric.js (Ubuntu)

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'd like to use `scale` to increase the `fontSize` of a text element. It seems to work on OSX, but it doesn't work in Chrome on Ubuntu:

[image]
See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/y7kLzj78/

So why does this:

```
text = new fabric.Text('foo', {
    fontSize: 10,
    left: 100,
    top: 10
});
```

produce something different than this on Ubuntu:

```
text = new fabric.Text('foo', {
    fontSize: 1,
    scaleX: 10,
    scaleY: 10,
    left: 100,
    top: 10
});
```

Comment: Your demo works for me on FF, Chrome on OSX http://i.imgur.com/ADdix9Q.png

Comment: I'm on an Ubuntu machine in Chrome.

Comment: Interesting. For me, on Chrome, it looks like [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7EDdF7qWY8_NThKTFI5anlrNGc/edit)

Comment: @Wex Windows 8.1 Pro

Comment: The Ubuntu browser doesn't use the same font(s) by default. What font-family are you using?

Comment: @BenSmith I have the same result on Chrome and Win 7

Comment: @ElliottFrisch good point, but does not seem to be dependent on the font. I've tried a few fonts that I'm certain are web-safe.

Comment: @Wex I just tried it on my ubuntu machine. They are identical here (completely blank), in Chrome and in Firefox. This machine is running 14.04 what version are you on?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 13.10

Comment: I'd be surprised if it was an issue with the O/S. Could it be a problem with the version of WebKit used by the different browsers?

Comment: @BenSmith - I'd be inclined to believe that it was an OS problem if the unscaled text looked as bad as the scaled text.

Comment: I vaguely remember coming across this issue before.. I think some systems doesn't scale the font size with transform. we had to supplement a css file to reduce font-size when we were forced to scale down site content by 50% to comply with some old IOS app that contained a webbrowser instance that ignores meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum font size in fabric js is 5 to work with scaleX and ScaleY at a time, so you need to give font size more than 5 in this case and you have to change your scalling formula to match minimum font size. Hope this helps